# コンテナのファイルシステム内の一部ファイルの差し替えについて

Tags: docker, jenkins

【質問経緯】

1. DockerをRHEL7.5 上に導入し、Docker Hubから最新のJenkinsのイメージをpull。
2. ただ、Jenkinsの公式が公開しているJenkinsイメージのバージョンが2.6.Xと古いため、
   pipeline等の一部のプラグインがインストールできません。
3. そこで、/var/lib/docker/overlay2/XXX(コンテナID?)/diff/usr/share/jenkins 
   ディレクトリ配下に存在するjenkins.warを、公式から落としてきた最新バージョンの物に
   差し替えてコンテナを立ち上げたところ、最新バージョンのjenkinsが立ち上がり、
   プラグインのインストールも行える様になりました。

【質問内容】
Docker Hub等で公開されているイメージのバージョンが古い場合、上記の様な対処方法で問題が
無いか(そもそもDocker、Jenkinsが公式として想定している方法かどうか)に関しまして、
ご存知の方がいましたら教えて頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

### Jenkinsのバージョンについて

[公式Dockerhubレポジトリ](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/)のドキュメントから、[公式のDockerfile](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/7e871e754b9e1a69791293af9cbe3501967856f4/Dockerfile#L45-L53)を確認したところ、2.121.1のバージョンが指定されているようです。また、念の為実際に自分でも`docker pull jenkins/jenkins && docker run jenkins/jenkins`というコマンドで確認したところ、2.141のJenkinsが起動しました。
そのため、おっしゃっているバージョンが古い問題はそもそも起きないはずです。
おそらく、[deprecatedの旧公式リポジトリ](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/)を利用してしまっているか、あるいは`:lts`タグを使われているのではないでしょうか。

### Dockerファイルの中身を差し替えて対処する方法に問題がないか

実行すること自体に問題はないと考えられますが、Dockerを利用するメリットが失われているように感じます。

Comment: 迅速な回答、ありがとうございました。
回答者様の仰られている様に、deprecatedの旧公式リポジトリを指定してしまっていました。

回答頂きましたコマンドをこれから実施してみようと思います。